# Operating with "hh:mm" Java

Tags: java, mysql, date, localtime

I have a table with a range of hours and minutes, "07:00" till "14:00" and a Java Api that gets these values.
At first I was using seconds (28800 to 50400).

I want to get all the values in between for every 5 minutes ("07:05", "07:10", "07:15", "07:20"... "08:15"... "13:55", "14:00").

But I cant quite figure how to do this in a clean way.

Class method (on console works great but the output of the api is in nano seconds:

```
@Transient
public List<LocalTime> getHorarios(){

    long initialCapacity = 0;
    List<LocalTime> times = new ArrayList<LocalTime> ( ( int ) initialCapacity );
    while (  ! nextTime.isAfter ( stop ) ) {
        times.add ( nextTime );
        nextTime = nextTime.plusMinutes ( 5 );
    }
    return times;
}

@Transient
public List<LocalTime> getHorariosLibres(List<LocalTime> horariosTomados){

    List<LocalTime> horariosLibres = getHorarios();
    horariosLibres.removeAll(horariosTomados);
    return horariosLibres;
}
```

So far this is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/horario/{fecha}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Object queryHorariosLibres(@PathVariable("fecha") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date fecha) {
    List<LocalTime> horariosTomados = turnoService.getHorariosTomados(fecha);
    Calendar dia = new GregorianCalendar();
    dia.setTime(fecha);
    Horario horario = horarioRepository.findByDia(dia.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));  
    List<LocalTime> horariosLibres = horario.getHorariosLibres(horariosTomados);

    return horariosLibres;
}
```

Actual output through API:

```
   [{"hour":7,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":7,"minute":5,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":7,"minute":10,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":7,"minute":15,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":7,"minute":20,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":7,"minute":25,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":7,"minute":30,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":7,"minute":35,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":7,"minute":40,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":7,"minute":45,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":7,"minute":50,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":7,"minute":55,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":8,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":8,"minute":5,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":8,"minute":10,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":8,"minute":15,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":8,"minute":20,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":8,"minute":25,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":8,"minute":30,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":8,"minute":35,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":8,"minute":40,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":8,"minute":45,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":8,"minute":50,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":8,"minute":55,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":9,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":9,"minute":5,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":9,"minute":10,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":9,"minute":15,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":9,"minute":20,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":9,"minute":25,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":9,"minute":30,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":9,"minute":35,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":9,"minute":40,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":9,"minute":45,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":9,"minute":50,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":9,"minute":55,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":10,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":10,"minute":5,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":10,"minute":10,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":10,"minute":15,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":10,"minute":20,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":10,"minute":25,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":10,"minute":30,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":10,"minute":35,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":10,"minute":40,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":10,"minute":45,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":10,"minute":50,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":10,"minute":55,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":11,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":11,"minute":5,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":11,"minute":10,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":11,"minute":15,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":11,"minute":20,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":11,"minute":25,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":11,"minute":30,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":11,"minute":35,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":11,"minute":40,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":11,"minute":45,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":11,"minute":50,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":11,"minute":55,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":12,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":12,"minute":5,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":12,"minute":10,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":12,"minute":15,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":12,"minute":20,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":12,"minute":25,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":12,"minute":30,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":12,"minute":35,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":12,"minute":40,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":12,"minute":45,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":12,"minute":50,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":12,"minute":55,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":13,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":13,"minute":5,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":13,"minute":10,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":13,"minute":15,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":13,"minute":20,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":13,"minute":25,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":13,"minute":30,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":13,"minute":35,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":13,"minute":40,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":13,"minute":45,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":13,"minute":50,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":13,"minute":55,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":14,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}]
```

Comment: What does your question have to do with the `mysql` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to roll-your-own data type here.

## `java.time.LocalTime`

Java 8 and later has a data type to fit this case: [`java.time.LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html), a time without date and without time zone. Use this for your business logic. From these objects you can generate a String representation for display to the user.

## `java.sql.Time`

JDBC has a data type for transferring such values in and out of your database: [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html).

```
String inputStart = "07:00";
String inputStop = "14:00";

LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse ( inputStart );
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse ( inputStop );
LocalTime nextTime = start;

Duration duration = Duration.ofMinutes ( 5 );

long initialCapacity = ( Duration.between ( start , stop ).toMinutes () / duration.toMinutes () ) + 1;  // Optional line of code.  Could be omitted.
List<LocalTime> times = new ArrayList ( ( int ) initialCapacity );
while (  ! nextTime.isAfter ( stop ) ) {
    times.add ( nextTime );
    nextTime = nextTime.plus ( duration );  //  Or call .plusMinutes( int ) and pass a number of minutes.
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "times: " + times + " initialCapacity: " + initialCapacity + " times.size " + times.size () );
```

> times: [07:00, 07:05, 07:10, 07:15, 07:20, 07:25, 07:30, 07:35, 07:40, 07:45, 07:50, 07:55, 08:00, 08:05, 08:10, 08:15, 08:20, 08:25, 08:30, 08:35, 08:40, 08:45, 08:50, 08:55, 09:00, 09:05, 09:10, 09:15, 09:20, 09:25, 09:30, 09:35, 09:40, 09:45, 09:50, 09:55, 10:00, 10:05, 10:10, 10:15, 10:20, 10:25, 10:30, 10:35, 10:40, 10:45, 10:50, 10:55, 11:00, 11:05, 11:10, 11:15, 11:20, 11:25, 11:30, 11:35, 11:40, 11:45, 11:50, 11:55, 12:00, 12:05, 12:10, 12:15, 12:20, 12:25, 12:30, 12:35, 12:40, 12:45, 12:50, 12:55, 13:00, 13:05, 13:10, 13:15, 13:20, 13:25, 13:30, 13:35, 13:40, 13:45, 13:50, 13:55, 14:00] initialCapacity: 85 times.size 85

For input into a database, convert to `java.sql.Time`.

```
java.sql.Time sqlTime = java.sql.Time.valueOf( myLocalTime );
```

## Time Zone

**Important:** Be aware that both your original code and this java.time code example are only using imaginary times-of-day that assume a *fictitious 24-hour generic day*. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) means that days are not always 24-hours long. Some of your listed times may not exist on a particular date in a particular time zone.

If you care about real moments, valid times on certain dates, use the `java.time.ZonedDateTime` (or `.OffsetDateTime`). For database transfer, use `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: [{"hour":7,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":7,"minute":5,"second":0,"nano":0},{"hour":7,"minute":10,"second":0,"nano":0},etc

Im getting that as the output, could you help me see the error updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would work with minutes as unit and use % and /. Something like

```
Map<String,Integer> storage = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for (int i=420; i< 840; i+=5)
{
     int hours = (i / 60);
     int minutes = (i % 60);
     String hourMinuteString = String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" 
                                      + String.format("%02d", minutes);
     storage.put(hourMinuteString, i);
}
```

Then you can retrieve the number of minutes by

```
 storage.get("10:45");
```

Comment: And then make the conversion back to minutes in the frontend using angularjs?
Or make the api itself understand and convert back to minutes?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you: Didn't you want to generate all Strings from "07:00" to "14:00"? Or do you want to do something else?

Comment: I need to show the strings to the user so he can pick the right time, but then I'll have to convert the string  back to minutes to save it to the db.

Comment: I wouldn't convert it back. I would use a HashMap to store the minutes for each String that you generate. Then you can just look them up.

Comment: Would you give me an example for this?

Comment: I extended the answer.